# .ajax() appends 'data' key values to URL even in POST mode

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

This is my code for the .ajax() call:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      }
```

In addition to using `type:"POST"` as above, I also tried using `$.ajaxSetup({type: "post"});` above this code block.

In both cases, the values in the `data` key are being appended to the URL. **I want a clean URL with no parameters.** This code is actually a part of an autocomplete field, it's wrapped into an anonymous function and given a key `source` like the main jQueryUI examples.

*Note* The actual URL is immaterial, I don't know if geonames supports POST requests but that's going to change later, this is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add your parameters like this :

```
url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON/" + param,
```

If you want to force POST, you can try [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? This looks like I'll end up with GET variables again? I want them to be in POST.

Comment: But, as understand correctly your question is "how can I append parameters to my url?"

Comment: No, the Parameters are already being appended, despite me specifying I want it to POST. I want a clean URL with no appended variables.

Comment: GET variables will end in a url like this one : http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON/?featureClass=P&style=full&maxRows=12&name_startsWith=request_term while appending parameters to your url will result in something like : http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON/P/full/12/request_term.

Comment: Ok now I get it. What makes you say they are appended to the url?

Comment: Firebug tells me that the URL being accessed is: `http://URL/city_state?featureClass=P&maxRows=12&name_startsWith=at&style=full` - but I need it to have just `http://URL/city_state/` and the variables to be sent via POST.

Comment: I also like the way the appended variables look, I'll test if that'll work - it's an acceptable compromise.

Comment: adeneo's answer is perfectly what I needed. But you discussed the problem and you were pretty close to the solution just before his answer came, so accepting yours. Thank you.

Comment: Note that jsonp is not part of $.post datatypes list

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to make a POST request with the JSONP datatype.

JSONP works by creating a `<script>` tag that executes Javascript from a different domain, it is not possible to send a POST request using a `<script>` tag.

If you specify `dataType: "jsonp"` and `type: "POST"`, the "jsonp" takes precedent and it gets sent as a "GET" request (the "POST" gets ignored).

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thanks! But HighKickX worked with me via the comments and his question about 'have you tried json' came just one minute before your answer. Since you have a huge rep by comparison, I hope you won't mind me accepting his answer and upvoting yours? :)

Comment: Sure, no problem! Just thought I'd explain why a jsonp request won't ever work with POST.